# How to destructure an array with elements of different types in typescript

Tags: typescript, destructuring

The following code example works fine in javascript:

```
 const f = ()=> { return[true,"text",11]; }
 const [active,status,numberEleven] = f();
 const twelve = numberEleven + 1;
```

However, `const twelve = numberEleven + 1;` throws an error in typescript because numberEleven could be either a string, a boolean or a number:
I've tried to change the function return types:

```
const f = ()=> {
  const res: [boolean, string, number] = [true, warning, score];
  return res;
}
```

But it didn't work. I then tried to change the type of the deconstructed array like so:

```
 const [active,status,numberEleven]: [boolean, string, number] = f();
```

But this approach resulted in the following error:

```
Type '(string | number | boolean)[]' is not assignable to type '[boolean, string, number]'.
  Target requires 3 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

So, what's the best way to destructure an array with elements of different types in typescript?
Thanks!

Comment: Your second option works (https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgDGEB2BneAzOAXjgAoBKQgPkRTjgx3imGwC44BtAIwggBtgAQ0wAaOLigBLTAHMxmAK4BbLsCgBdIpxhQFwEQCIYoGAZEBGc+oDctOMxgKomey1up6WXJ0FoYkgDd9XEFHbBFFFTUAUQEgzE1iPHJbT0Y4GAB3YD4grUjVKFjgeLgAajhzayA) The other version would be a `as const`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgDGEB2BneAzOAXjgAoBKQgPjgG0YoBXYAGgCIZQZXmBGHgXTgBDbHAw4YAbhRisuWkLQwAlgDcWuITAbZmmBgFsARsCgBRADbB1mQcTzlpsiXBgB3YBfVE4+46ctrYEw4AGo4HkkgA

Comment: Please consider reviewing the guidelines for [ask] and what constitutes a [mre].  When you show code and something is not working about it, it doesn't help to just say "but it didn't work". It is expected that you describe exactly what is not working... is there an error message? If so, what is it and where does it happen?  Is there some unexpected output? What and where? Since the version you say "didn't work" actually does work in the TS Playground, right now the problem isn't reproducible and thus the question might be closed unless you rectify it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the second option works. The error I shared was being caused by another block of code.
thanks Dragomir! <3

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```js
const f = () => {
  return [true, "text", 11] as const;
}

const [active,status,numberEleven] = f();
const twelve = numberEleven + 1;
```